# JavaScript прикрипления к переменной

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем доброй ночи...есть у меня проблема,немогу решить кто поможет буду благодарен

есть Angular модель

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.phones = journal
});
```

и список, в который я вывожу переменную журнал

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <p>{{phone.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

В переменной журнал находятся мастера, одного из них мне нужно прикрепить к заказу при нажатии

МНЕ НУЖНО ПРИ КЛИКЕ НА ЭЛЕМЕНТ ПОМЕСТИТЬ ЕГО В ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ

вот таким образом

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p id="one">Григоривй</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p id="two">Андрей</p>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready( function () {

    $("#one").bind("click", addSpectorOne); 

});
function addSpectorOne () {
    var a = $('#one').text();
}
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#two").bind("click", addSpectorTwo); 
});
function addSpectorTwo () {
    var a = $('#two').text();
}
```

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="doer in $ctrl.doers" ng-click="$ctrl.handlerDoerAppend(item)">`

Comment: Не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Лучше отредактировать самый первый.

Comment: рекомендую [ознакомиться](https://metanit.com/web/angular/1.1.php), свое знакомство начинал именно с этого ресурса

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один вопрос снова и снова. Если хотите уточнить свой вопрос - просто отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 1):

а почему бы не создать массив мастеров, например так:

```
$scope.masters = [];
$scope.select = function(master){
    //реализация логики
}
```

а в представлении вывести его аналогично *телефонам*

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="master in masters">
        <p ng-click="select(master)">{{master.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да собственно, так и надо сделать.